# intellij idea 14 color preview in xml editor

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

I updated IntelliJ Idea from 13 to 14 and I noticed that in XML file editor the little square representing a color preview (you can find it on the left near line number) has disappeared.
I't still available on the xml editor while editing Layout files in android, but it's not available anymore on the normal xml editor.
Can I turn it on somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try

File - Settings - Editor -> Appereance -> Show CSS color preview icon in gutter

Comment: does it work in your case? I tried on the 13th release to turn it off and on the 14th to turn it on, and I was not successful in both cases. In the while I keep using the 13th. Thanks anyway!